# OAUTH2 Django problems with client_secret

Tags: django, django-oauth

I was updating an old non documented project, database, users, etc..

Suddenly it came a problem, the client_secret_id is not hashed, if I edited in /o/applications then it become hashed.

Is there a simple way to hash every client_secret_id other than manually do it one by one, application per application?

I found the library, but I don't have any idea where is the salt, or how to include it

Comment: Generally when it comes to programming, most tasks can be automated. What steps are you doing if you did it manually?  Can you think of ways to write scripts to let the computer perform those steps for you? You can for example easily write a script that opens a file, find a value and replace it with another value.